# SetTimout in react export function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, settimeout

What is the right way to add setTimeout in this function?
Next js WP headless CMS

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
      const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
      return {
        props: {
          allPosts
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: You could use Javascript's promise, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This might get what you want

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    return setTimeout( async () => {

        // executes this block of code after the timeout(2 seconds)
        const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
        return {
            props: {
                allPosts
            }
        };
    }, 2000) //2 seconds (2 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Error: Your `getStaticProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?

Comment: I've updated it, if it doesn't work you might want to go with @MAP 's answer, its going to make things cleaner.

Comment: u need to return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
   return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
        res({ props: { allPosts } })
       }, 2000)
   })
}
```

Basically returning a promise that will be resolved after 2 seconds. This way you can use `await getStaticProps()` in other functions.